# HTML image not being displayed on Chrome, or Safari web browsers and is returning 404 error when I inspect the page

Tags: html, image

For some reason when I try to insert an image in my website it is not being displayed in Chrome, or Safari web browsers. When I inspect the page, it is showing that there is a 404 error for the image I am trying to display which is the "software" image. I have a sample code below. The service image is displayed fine, but the software image is showing an error that reads "Sorry, this page doesn't exist. Please check the URL or go back a page. 404 Error. Page Not Found" when I inspect the page.

```
<!doctype html>
```

`

```
</head>
<body>
    <img id="software" src="images/software (1).png" alt="">
    <img id="service-image" src="images/service.jpeg">
</body>
```

`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question with some relevant code. It's currently not clear what is currently happening and what you'd like to happen: `When I insert certain images into the body of the code and refresh the live server, I am seeing the image displayed there, but not on the actual webpage.`

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. You say you see the photos are loaded in some instances yet not others... What is unique to the browsers that can access the photos, and what is unique to the ones that cannot? Try forcibly clearing the cache for browsers that cannot load them with `CTRL + SHIFT + R`.

Comment: I apologize, I have edited my question. I hope it is more clear. I have been stuck on this issue for days. It is unlike anything I have seen before

Comment: Just because I'm curious: did you ever get this working?

Comment: Yes, I did, but instead of pulling the image from the folder, I instead needed to use the url address in order for it to be displayed. It was an odd fix, but this was the only way it would work for the rest of the images in the file. I had to save the photos in my google photos and use a google embed website to convert their links to a respectable HTML url that I then placed inside the image tag.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, so far, without (of course) having seen your code.

But, how are you referencing the images in your `image` tags?

Are you using a relative path (relative to the root of your website), or are you spelling all of it out *using the file's file system location*?  So that the URL looks something like "C:\hibbert\TDAT\images\image001.jpg"?

If you do the latter, you will get the results you're describing, because the HTML will be telling the browser "Look for this file in the file system of the computer you're running on", and the only computer that has that file is the server.

Comment: I edited my question so you could see how I was referencing my images. I have done this for all of my photos, but it was not until recently that certain photos would not work with this method. The images are displayed in the live server before I upload my files to the web, but when the files are loaded to the web, I can not see the images on Chrome, or Safari web browsers.

Comment: Do the files have anything in common, like all having spaces in their names? (You could try encoding the file name with %20 in place of the space. See if that makes a difference.)

Comment: I just tried putting the %20 in place of the space, but still nothing. I have two files both with spaces. The first is "software (1).png" and the second is "software (2).png."

Answer (score 0):

Did you try placing an alt text as if the site couldn’t display the image it will show the text of what is supposed to be there that way you will know if the file path is wrong

Also what is your text editor as vsCode can help you write your file path to make sure it is correct

Insert something like this into the image tag and see if that works

alt=“image goes here”

Comment: Yes, I have just added the alt text and it is being displayed. What does this mean about the photo?

Comment: It could mean that the image path is not right are you pulling it from a different folder outside of the project? Also I just notice that in your file there is a space between service (1) if your image file has a space you need to remove it as code does not recognize spaces so it should be like service(1)

Comment: You have to write it like this or remove the space entirely <img src="buttons/service%20(1).png" />

Comment: And your img tags should also be self closing

Comment: It should close like this />

Comment: I have just tried self closing that image tag and also renaming the image file excluding the space and still nothing. Also, the image is located within the images folder which is located inside the original website folder which is located inside of another folder called HTML. So the order of the folders is as follows HTML > TDAT (website folder) > images > software.png

Comment: ok so is this html file stored in the root directory or in a different folder

Comment: I am not too sure, could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: is the html file In the main folder of your directory so not in sitting in any folders just outside of the directory

Comment: There is a main folder named "HTML' and inside of this folder is another folder with all of the website files inside of it, as well as a folder for the images. This is where the html file is located. So, yes, the HTML file is technically sitting inside of another folder outside of the main folder.